# What does this pedal notation mean for the piano?

Tags: piano, notation, keyboard-pedals

I've never seen this pedal notation used before and would appreciate it if someone could help me understand what it means?[image: pedal markings]

Comment: This is Beethoven's Pathétique Sonata, mvt. 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The └ mark means "apply pedal", and the ┐ mark means "release pedal".

Here is a more standard notation from the [Godowsky edition](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/c/c9/IMSLP11070-Godowsky_APS_16_Beethoven_Sonate_pathetique.pdf) of the piece:<sup>1</sup>

[image: Beethoven Pathetique Sonata mm 1-2]

---

<sup>1</sup>Ludwig van Beethoven, Sonata in C Minor (1798), Op. 13, "Pathétique", mm. 1-2. The pedal markings both in the OP and Godowsky are editorial, not Beethoven's. Beethoven did not give pedal indications here.

Comment: Surely that sign would be more intuitive with an upturn at the end, showing which way the pedal actually goes.

Comment: Yup.  Which is probably why the more standard pedal line does that, with 'Ped' at the beginning and an upturn at the end.  I like this one though.  Less cluttered than all those 'Ped' objects.

Answer (score 3):

The beginning of the pedal mark indicates that you need to suppress the sustain pedal and at the end it needs to be released.